# Rails 5 API - Modifying the 'index' response object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple `index` function

```
def index

    @campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params[:campaign_id])
    @characters = @campaign.characters
    render json: {
        characters: @characters
    }
end
```

This works as intended, but one of the attributes is an `id` that is a reference to another table. To avoid the front-end having to solve for this I would prefer the backend to respond with the correct details.

Temporarily I have handled this in the create method

```
 def create
        @campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params[:campaign_id])
        @charClass = CharClass.find_by_id(params[:character_char_class_id]).class_name
        @character = @campaign.characters.new(character_params)
        @character.char_class_id = params[:character_char_class_id]

        if @character.save!
            render status: 201, json: {

                message: "Successfull added this character to the campaign!",
                character_name: @character.character_name + ' the ' + @charClass,
                character_class: @charClass,
                character_level: @character.character_level,
                character_experience: @character.character_experience,
                character_gold: @character.character_gold,
                character_perks: get_names(@character.character_perks),

            }
        else
            render status: 404, json: {
                message: "Something went wrong: Check line 24 of the Character Controller"
            }
        end
    end
```

However, this feels wrong because `Characters` already knows of the `Char_Class` relation. (Removed useless info)

```
  create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "character_class" # I added this
    t.integer "char_class_id" # This was already here
    t.index ["campaign_id"], name: "index_characters_on_campaign_id"
    t.index ["char_class_id"], name: "index_characters_on_char_class_id"
  end
```

So I am able to do something like `Character.first.charChass.class_name` and I will get the raw text output, as you see in the create: But how could I do this within the controller (or model?)

I will be doing a flow like this for numerous models so I am thinking I won't want to keep with this method.

Comment: What's that attribute. How are your models related?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thought the schema would show. Character has a `char_class` based on `char_class_id` - Attribute is `class_name` in `CharClass` model, `char_class_id` in `Character` model